# How to separate modules in different View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

In my iOS 8.0 app,

`HomeViewController` is the main `UIViewcontroller` in my project.

I have no option but to Put my animation and click events code in a separate file.

1. Social integration feature and code, Can I put my code in separate file for FB and Twitter.

How can I make my FB and Twitter code in a separate view controller?

Comment: It sounds like your `HomeViewController` is both a container (including slide view controller coding and page curl coding) and a manager for some of the screens contained therein (including click events code). Is that a valid observation?

Comment: Main it is a container, container for Page Curl and Slide View controller.

Comment: For slide View controller I have taken a separate view controller.

Comment: For Page curl I have not implemented yet, but will contain separate view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you start reading how to **structure an iOS app**. There are different styles for different designed patterns.

- [iOS Design Patterns (Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DesignPatterns.html)
- [How should I structure my iOS app? (Quora)](http://www.quora.com/How-should-I-structure-my-iOS-app)

Also, would be good to take a look at the [good practices guides.](https://github.com/futurice/ios-good-practices)

Answer (score 0):

You can make several classes and by making objects of those classes you can call there function by passing some values from your viewcontroller.

To handle the response from those classes you can either use delegate or return types of functions.

Comment: I think the code will be more complex, show me somewhat exactly in Objective C. Thanks for answering but, I am , How I will be implementing ?

Comment: Hey Arpit here is the link (https://drive.google.com/a/synchsoft.in/file/d/0B-fSuniksNAuUnlMQ1lFZ3o0Sk0/view?usp=sharing) of detail.
Where you can make a class and use that from other classes.